# I have some problems with ActionBarActivity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, android-actionbaractivity

I'm trying a calendar apps in Android Studio.

I cloned it from github and now I have some problems.

I imported `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` but it keeps showing the message:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'ActionBarActivity'
```

And there is also a warning message that says:

```
Can't start Git: D:\tests\simple\settings.gradle Probably the path to Git executable is not valid. Fix it.
```

How can I fix these problem?
Please help me.
[image]

Comment: I used github with SourceTree

Comment: did you add appcompat in project structure?

Comment: Make sure you have ` compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+' ` inside `dependencies` in build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

The [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) is included in the [AppCompat support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat).

To use it, **you have to add the appcompat library in your project**.

If you are using Android Studio, just add a dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    // Support Libraries (it requires api 23 to compile)
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

If you are using Eclipse you can read this [official link](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res).

**Also pay attention.**
**This class is deprecated.**
Use [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added your dependency to `build.gradle`, run a Gradle Sync.
Also note the `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated, because it has been replaced by `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Android has deprecated `ActionBar`. Instead, try to use `ToolBar` which gives you more flexibility than `ActionBar` and extend `AppCompactActivity` instead of `ActionbarActivity`. This will solve your problem for sure.

Comment: thnx @Bas  my bad just typed it without seeing thanks mate